# Idea how to make a storage app in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, storage

I started an android studio a few days ago. Watched some beginner tutorials. Got some basics.
My idea is to make my small storage app to have some buttons(types of storage) that will lead me to a new activity, and then in that activity to have a list of items, each of those items would have a TextView displaying a number of units, a button + and -, to add or subtract a number in that TextView, and an image next to it. So this would be a template. This activity would be scrollable and have let us say a few dozen items.

Example:

[image]

I managed to make it work, but coding every single one of these elements to save the value with sharedpreferences, and then link the items id's etc (if there are for example 20) it takes too much time. I guess im doing it by foot. It took me 2h to fill up just 6 elements.

Idea that i would like, is to have in each of those activities a + button which will generate a new item below a template, which opens lets say a form where i can browse the image, enter the items name, the quantaty and so it has the logic inside (saving the number the name picture etc), which will also save the value when app is closed,and have add or substract with a plus/minus button.
My question would be, can you give me a clue, some maybe videos or something that would be related to this. I tried googling it and yt but it was kinda a dead end. Or i was searching for the wrong keywords.

Here is my xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@mipmap/backgroundd"
tools:context=".Arduino">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#6EFFFFFF"
    android:text="Arduino"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:text="Back"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.979"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageBMP280"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@drawable/picture_border"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.055"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.533"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/bmp_280" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnbmp280minus"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.771" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvbmp280"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/number_border"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.671"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.737" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnbmp280plus"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.854"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.785" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/BMP280"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="BMP 280"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.709"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and so on with same constraint layout, it was just copy pasted 20 times.

And for the activity java.

```
public class Arduino extends AppCompatActivity {

//Deklaracija objekata iz xml
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private Button bmp280minus;
private Button bmp280plus;
private TextView infoBMP280;

private Button Buck3Aminus;
private Button Buck3Aplus;
private TextView infoBuck3A;

private Button Encoderminus;
private Button Encoderplus;
private TextView infoEncoder;

private Button ESP8266minus;
private Button ESP8266plus;
private TextView infoESP8266;

private Button FTDIminus;
private Button FTDIplus;
private TextView infoFTDI;

private Button GPSminus;
private Button GPSplus;
private TextView infoGPS;

//Deklaracija promenljivih koje ce se koristiti za cuvanje vrednosti
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private int bmp280;
private int Buck3A;
private int Encoder;
private int ESP8266;
private int FTDI;
private int GPS;
private int HC05;
private int HCSR04;
private int HCSR501;
private int HX711;
private int Joystick;
private int LCD16x2;
private int LED100;
private int LEDMatrixBig;
private int LEDMatrixSmall;
private int ProtoboardSmall;
private int ProtoboardBig;
private int CAN;
private int MG90S;
private int MG996R;
private int BuckMini;
private int ArduinoNano;
private int Relay1CH;
private int RF433;
private int RGBDiode;
private int RTC;
private int SG90;
private int DHT22;
private int ArduinoUno;
private int USBMiniB;
private int TTL;

//Ime fajla u kom ce se cuvati vrednosti
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "ArduinoValues"; // ovde smo zapravo stavili fajl koji ce se sacuvati sta

@Override
//Funkcija koja cuva vrednosti
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // ovo kreiramo i unutar njega pravimo ove sharedpreferences

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_arduino); // ovde stavljamo na koji layout ce nam biti prikazano

    configureMainButton();
    seeNumberOfQuantity();

    //Deklaracija klase
    SharedPreferences settingsBMP280 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
    SharedPreferences settingsBuck3A = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences settingsEncoder = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);// ova funkcija gde ce se storovati vrednost od bmp280 , kako se dodaje nova tako treba nova promenljiva settings i mode da se poveca za 1
    SharedPreferences settingsESP8266 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences settingsFTDI = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences settingsGPS = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

    bmp280 = settingsBMP280.getInt("bmp280",bmp280); // ova linija kaze da postavimo vrednost bmp280 koja je promenljiva na vrednost koja se nalazi unutar tog fajla
    Buck3A = settingsBuck3A.getInt("Buck3A", Buck3A);
    Encoder = settingsEncoder.getInt("Encoder", Encoder);
    ESP8266 = settingsESP8266.getInt("ESP8266", ESP8266);
    FTDI = settingsFTDI.getInt("FTDI", FTDI);
    FTDI = settingsGPS.getInt("GPS", GPS);

    //BMP 280 *********************************************************************************************
    bmp280minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // sta zapravo radi kada se pritisne - dugme na bmp280 minus
            if(bmp280 != 0)
                bmp280--;
            infoBMP280.setText(String.valueOf(bmp280));
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit(); // ovaj editor isto treba da se menja kada se dodaje novo
            editor.putInt("bmp280",bmp280); // i ovde
            editor.commit(); // kao i ovde mora editor da se povecava za 1
        }
    });
    bmp280plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // sta zapravo radi kada se pritisne + dugme na bmp280 plus
            bmp280++;
            infoBMP280.setText(String.valueOf(bmp280));
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt("bmp280",bmp280);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
    infoBMP280.setText(String.valueOf(bmp280)); // setuje vrednost na text view od promenljive bmp280

    //Buck 3A ************************************************************************************************
    Buck3Aminus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // sta zapravo radi kada se pritisne - dugme na bmp280 minus
            if(Buck3A != 0)
                Buck3A--;
            infoBuck3A.setText(String.valueOf(Buck3A));
            SharedPreferences settingsBuck3A = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorBuck3A = settingsBuck3A.edit(); // ovaj editor isto treba da se menja kada se dodaje novo
            editorBuck3A.putInt("Buck3A",Buck3A); // i ovde
            editorBuck3A.commit(); // kao i ovde mora editor da se povecava za 1
        }
    });
    Buck3Aplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // sta zapravo radi kada se pritisne + dugme na bmp280 plus
            Buck3A++;
            infoBuck3A.setText(String.valueOf(Buck3A));
            SharedPreferences settingsBuck3A = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorBuck3A = settingsBuck3A.edit();
            editorBuck3A.putInt("Buck3A",Buck3A);
            editorBuck3A.commit();
        }
    });
    infoBuck3A.setText(String.valueOf(Buck3A)); // setuje vrednost na text view od promenljive bmp280

    //Encoder ************************************************************************************************
    Encoderminus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // sta zapravo radi kada se pritisne - dugme na bmp280 minus
            if(Encoder != 0)
                Encoder--;
            infoEncoder.setText(String.valueOf(Encoder));
            SharedPreferences settingsEncoder = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorEncoder = settingsEncoder.edit(); // ovaj editor isto treba da se menja kada se dodaje novo
            editorEncoder.putInt("Encoder",Encoder); // i ovde
            editorEncoder.commit(); // kao i ovde mora editor da se povecava za 1
        }
    });
    Encoderplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // sta zapravo radi kada se pritisne + dugme na bmp280 plus
            Encoder++;
            infoEncoder.setText(String.valueOf(Encoder));
            SharedPreferences settingsEncoder = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorEncoder = settingsEncoder.edit();
            editorEncoder.putInt("Encoder",Encoder);
            editorEncoder.commit();
        }
    });
    infoEncoder.setText(String.valueOf(Encoder)); // setuje vrednost na text view od promenljive bmp280

    //ESP8266 ************************************************************************************************
    ESP8266minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // sta zapravo radi kada se pritisne - dugme na bmp280 minus
            if(ESP8266 != 0)
                ESP8266--;
            infoESP8266.setText(String.valueOf(ESP8266));
            SharedPreferences settingsESP8266 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorESP8266 = settingsESP8266.edit(); // ovaj editor isto treba da se menja kada se dodaje novo
            editorESP8266.putInt("ESP8266",ESP8266); // i ovde
            editorESP8266.commit(); // kao i ovde mora editor da se povecava za 1
        }
    });
    ESP8266plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // sta zapravo radi kada se pritisne + dugme na bmp280 plus
            ESP8266++;
            infoESP8266.setText(String.valueOf(ESP8266));
            SharedPreferences settingsESP8266 = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorESP8266 = settingsESP8266.edit();
            editorESP8266.putInt("ESP8266",ESP8266);
            editorESP8266.commit();
        }
    });
    infoESP8266.setText(String.valueOf(ESP8266)); // setuje vrednost na text view od promenljive bmp280

    //FTDI ************************************************************************************************
    FTDIminus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // sta zapravo radi kada se pritisne - dugme na bmp280 minus
            if(FTDI != 0)
                FTDI--;
            infoFTDI.setText(String.valueOf(FTDI));
            SharedPreferences settingsFTDI = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorFTDI = settingsFTDI.edit(); // ovaj editor isto treba da se menja kada se dodaje novo
            editorFTDI.putInt("FTDI",FTDI); // i ovde
            editorFTDI.commit(); // kao i ovde mora editor da se povecava za 1
        }
    });
    FTDIplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // sta zapravo radi kada se pritisne + dugme na bmp280 plus
            FTDI++;
            infoFTDI.setText(String.valueOf(FTDI));
            SharedPreferences settingsFTDI = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorFTDI = settingsFTDI.edit();
            editorFTDI.putInt("FTDI",FTDI);
            editorFTDI.commit();
        }
    });
    infoFTDI.setText(String.valueOf(FTDI)); // setuje vrednost na text view od promenljive bmp280

    //GPS ************************************************************************************************
    GPSminus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // sta zapravo radi kada se pritisne - dugme na bmp280 minus
            if(GPS != 0)
                GPS--;
            infoGPS.setText(String.valueOf(GPS));
            SharedPreferences settingsGPS = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorGPS = settingsGPS.edit(); // ovaj editor isto treba da se menja kada se dodaje novo
            editorGPS.putInt("GPS",GPS); // i ovde
            editorGPS.commit(); // kao i ovde mora editor da se povecava za 1
        }
    });
    GPSplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { // sta zapravo radi kada se pritisne + dugme na bmp280 plus
            GPS++;
            infoGPS.setText(String.valueOf(GPS));
            SharedPreferences settingsGPS = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editorGPS = settingsGPS.edit();
            editorGPS.putInt("GPS",GPS);
            editorGPS.commit();
        }
    });
    infoGPS.setText(String.valueOf(GPS)); // setuje vrednost na text view od promenljive bmp280



}

//Funkcija gde definisemo nase objekte sa cim su povezani iz layout-a
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void seeNumberOfQuantity(){ // Funkcija koja definise od BMP280 njegove dugmice i textview

    bmp280minus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnbmp280minus);
    bmp280plus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnbmp280plus);
    infoBMP280 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvbmp280);

    Buck3Aminus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBuck3Aminus);
    Buck3Aplus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBuck3Aplus);
    infoBuck3A = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBuck3A);

    Encoderminus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEncoderminus);
    Encoderplus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEncoderplus);
    infoEncoder = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvEncoder);

    ESP8266minus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnESP8266minus);
    ESP8266plus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnESP8266plus);
    infoESP8266 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvESP8266);

    FTDIminus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFTDIminus);
    FTDIplus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFTDIplus);
    infoFTDI = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvFTDI);

    GPSminus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGPSminus);
    GPSplus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGPSplus);
    infoGPS = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvGPS);
}

//Funkija za odlazak na prethodnou stranu
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void configureMainButton(){ // Funkcija koja setuje dugme za back znaci povratak na prvobitnu stranicu
    Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Main); // Nase dugme koje smo deklarovali kao backButton ide na Main stranicu
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

So basiclly this is going step by step, i would need some guidence on how to make this quicker, i order to make an 5,6 activities(types of storage) with over 100 items. I suppose that all hard work in java part could be done in some array kind of function, that i would parse the values of variables, but i guess i get stuck on how to make that function with calling each textview,button id etc.

I m having fun doing this, so would appreciate if you had some other guides that i could follow, some keywords of examples that are related to this etc.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SQLite. Search it on YouTube and there will be many tutorials.